# Linking error when trying to create new object of my class C++

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I'm trying to test my program by creating an object `SingleLinkedList m1;` of SingleLinkedList. If I don't create and operate on the object it compiles fine. Here is my main:

```
int main()
{
    SingleLinkedList m1;
    displayMenu();
    int user_menu;
    cin >> user_menu;   //get input from user which pocket they want to go to 
    while (user_menu != 4)  
    {
        displayChoices();
        int user_input; //
        cin >> user_input;
        if (user_input == 1) {
            cout << "You selected the Pocket Of Magic!" << endl;
            cout << "What do you choose to do?" << endl;
            //string user_choice;
            //cin >> user_choice;
            //SingleLinkedList m1;
            m1.operationMagic();    
        }
        else if (user_input == 2) {
            cout << "You selected the Pocket Of Potions!" << endl;
            cout << "What do you choose to do?" << endl;
        }

    user_input = 4;
    }
    displayMenu();
```

However, when I try to link, get this error:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "SingleLinkedList::SingleLinkedList()", referenced from:
      _main in pocketmaindriver-df9a60.o
  "SingleLinkedList::~SingleLinkedList()", referenced from:
      _main in pocketmaindriver-df9a60.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is the cause of this? I tried including the .cpp file as well and that did not work.Here is my .h file to compare:

```
#ifndef POCKET_OF_MAGIC_
#define POCKET_OF_MAGIC_

//using namespace std;


class SingleNode {
private:
    std::string value;
    SingleNode *nextNode;
public:
    SingleNode();
    SingleNode(std::string s); 
    std::string getValue(); 
    SingleNode* getNextNode(); 
    void setNextNode(SingleNode *newNode); 
};


class SingleLinkedList {
private:
    SingleNode *head;
    SingleNode *tail;
    int totalNodes;
    int itemCount;
public:
    SingleLinkedList();
    ~SingleLinkedList();
    void traverseAndPrint();
    void addNode(std::string data);
    bool deleteNode(std::string data);
    void operationMagic();

}; //end pocket of magic

#endif //end pocket of magic
```

Comment: It comes from the 'link command' => it's a linker error.

Comment: If you are having a build/link error, but might be apropos to include your `#include`s in your code section.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the command you're using to compile your program.

Comment: `I tried including the .cpp file `  No you can't just "try".  You *must* be able to include the definition of `Singleton::Singleton`, or else this won't work.  Maybe you are not adding your Singleton.cpp file (assuming this is where it's mplemented) to your project properly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Not quite sure what you mean. Here is my .cpp file:https://www.dropbox.com/s/dzk2ivxlc80rkra/PocketOfMagic.cpp?dl=0

Comment: @MilesBudnek  `g++ pocketmaindriver.cpp -std=c++11`

Comment: @Jeremy78 What I'm saying is that your project is supposed to 1) compile your CPP file and 2) Link your resulting Singleton object file to create your final executable.  You are missing either step 1) or step 2).

Comment: @Jeremy78 So how is the compiler and linker supposed to know about `Singleton.cpp` given the command line you have?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to C++. So would I have to do something like the answer below?

Comment: Your command line does exactly what you stated.  You compiled the `pocketmaindriver.cpp` source file and called the linker.  Nowhere did you tell the compiler or linker anything about `Singleton.cpp`.  In a multiple source file project, you are to list all the files that are to be compiled and linked, either on the command line, in a "make" file, or if you're using an IDE, in your project settings.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell the compiler about your class's .cpp file.  You need to do something like `g++ PocketOfMagic.cpp pocketmaindriver.cpp -o my_program`

Comment: Thanks. Do I not need the `-std=c++11` in the command line? Is the `-o my_program` stand for object file?

Comment: If you're using c++11 you need `-std=c++11`.  `-o my_program` just tells it what to name the output executable.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but I tried to compile `g++ PocketOfMagic.cpp pocketmaindriver.cpp -o -std=c++11` and received the same error.

Comment: @Jeremy78 I suggest you use an IDE to build C++ programs.  Then you just add the files you need to build into the IDE project, and then let the IDE figure out how to call g++ and the linker correctly.

Comment: I tried to use xcode but it won't let me build. But I put all my files in one file with declarations, got rid of the headers,  and renamed it. I still get the same error so I'm not sure this is my problem